I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') and I can't seem to find the source of the error
const userRegistrationPost = (req, res) => {
    const{name, email, pass1, pass2} = req.body;

        let errors = [];

        if(!name|| !email || !pass1 || !pass2){
            errors.push({msg: "Please ensure all fields are filled"});
        }

        if(pass1 !==pass2){
            errors.push({msg: "Passwords don't match"});
        }
        
        if(pass1.length < 6){   //line 66
            errors.push({msg: "Passwords must be at least 6 characters"});
        }

        if(errors.length > 0){
            res.render("user_registration", {errors, name, email, pass1, pass2})
        }else{
        //WE DON'T WANT TO HAVE 2 USERS WITH THE SAME EMAIL
            User.findOne({email: email})
            .then((result)=> {
                if(result){
                    errors.push({msg: "Email already exists"});
                    res.render("user_registration", errors, name, email, pass1, pass2)
                }else{
                    //HERE WE TRY TO ENCRYPT OUR PASSWORD
                    bcrypt.hash(pass1, 10, (error, hash)=>{
                        const nUser = new User({
                            name, email, password: hash,
                        })
                        try{
                            nUser.save();
                            req.flash('message', "Registration Successful. You can now Signup")
                            res.redirect('/user_login');
                        }
                        catch(err){
                            req.flash('error_msg', "Could not save into the Database");
                            res.redirect('user_registration');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch((err)=> {
                res.send("There's a problem");
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
}

It says the error occurs on line 66. It was supposed to save users into the database after inputing their details but it keeps giving me TypeError.

Which is line 66 from the code you shared?

if(pass1.length < 6){
errors.push({msg: "Passwords must be at least 6 characters"});
} //this is line 66

So the error implies that pass1 is undefined, right?

You  can try optional chaining like (pass1?.length < 6 ) and make sure the value pass1 get properly destructured from the  req.body.

Yes that is what it implies

What does console.log(req.body) say? Start there.

You can use optional chaining, like
        if(pass1?.length < 6){   //line 66
            errors.push({msg: "Passwords must be at least 6 characters"});
        }

but note that in this case, if pass1 is falsy, then its length will be evaluated as undefined and the comparison will be false. If this is just what you need (to have an error for pass1 being required, but to not show its length issue when it's not even defined), then good. If not, then you can further elaborate to (pass1?.length ?? 0) < 6.
